# List all the visualizations in Kibana 4.1.1

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Is there any way to get all the visualizations from Kibana 4.1.1 . As currently I can only get 100 visualizations . There are around 500 visualizations which i need a list of those .

Answer (score 0):

Solved it . Used this [script](http://air.ghost.io/kibana-4-export-and-import-visualizations-and-dashboards/) and exported all visualizations.